# Instructions in an ssh remote execution block are evaluated locally on the client side first. Why?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, remote-server

Why are the instructions in an ssh remote execution block evaluated locally on the client side first?

Consider the following code:

```
ssh -tt serverhostname "
   if [ `grep -cm 1 "string" /serverside/file`!= "1" ]; then
        echo "Doing some action on" `date`   
   fi
" 2> /dev/null
```

One might expect for the instructions listed in the ssh block to be executed on the remote.  This is not the case. The if statement is actually executed on the client side. Why? Is there a syntactically correct way to process the instructions server side (on the remote)?

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting additional info in an answer.

Comment: If you are asking about things like `date` and such being done locally that's because you are using double quotes. You need to escape anything in those quotes that you don't want to execute locally.

Comment: Specifically what in your code sample is wrongly being evaluated locally?

Comment: Because that's how the shell works - it evaluates a command line, performing several passes of different kinds of substitutions, splitting, etc. before it actually executes the resulting command. Using single quotes instead of double quotes would avoid certain parts of that process, but may still not do what you intended...

Comment: OK, folks. I've updated the question for clarity. double vs single quotes will do nothing to explain or resolve the phenomenon I'm describing here. Etan was on the right track, but again it has nothing to do with double quotes. I believe it has to do with the ssh session not having anywhere to store result of instruction for use in a subsequent instruction.

Comment: To answer Kenster: Both the if and the echo statements are evaluated on the remote server. The injected grep statement is evaluated locally on the client, though the intent is to evaluate the file on the server. Best answer goes to a better way than I've described below to have the server evaluate something (like grep a file), then use the result to evaluate something ( as shown with the if statement ) without having to use the client to store the result (as shown below holding the result in local client variable a).

Answer (score 0):

Unquoted and double-quoted arguments are expanded before the command is invoked:

```
ssh server "echo $HOSTNAME"
```

is the same as

```
ssh server "echo clienthostname"
```

and sends the literal string `echo clienthostname` to the server. The server therefore writes out the client's hostname.

Single quoted and escaped arguments, meanwhile, are not expanded:

```
ssh server 'echo $HOSTNAME'
ssh server "echo \$HOSTNAME"
```

will both send the literal string `echo $HOSTNAME` to the server, and therefore cause the server to write out the server's hostname.

This applies to all commands, and has nothing to do with ssh.

Answer (score -1):

I asked this question to perhaps help someone else having the same dilemma. You want to execute something on the server, and use the value of that instruction as the basis for something else. But you find the server isn't performing the instructions.

Bash is in fact performing the injected instruction client-side. The only work around I've found is to issue separate commands and have the result store client side. ie.

```
# Step 1
a=`ssh server grep -cm 1 "something" /serverside/file`
# Step 2
if [ $a != "1" ]; then
   ssh -tt server "
       echo "perform some series of tasks"
   "
fi
```